# Using PRXPARSE, PRXMATCH and SUBSTR functions to extract parts of the string in SAS

Tags: sas

Using PRXPARSE, PRXMATCH and SUBSTR functions in SAS 9.4 M6, the following code snippets extract parts of the string into two variables, fname and data_year and return the desired results.

```
Issue: NOTE: Invalid second argument to function SUBSTR at line 3159 column 30 for _N_ = 2. Please see the SAS Log below.
```

Question: What changes would I make to the program to prevent SAS from issuing the above note.

Any help with a resolution of the issue would be appreciated.

```
Data _Null_;
  retain re;
  if _N_ = 1 then do;
    re = PRXPARSE("/\d{4} | \d{4}-d{4}/");
  end;

  length data_year $10   fname $100; 
  infile datalines length = reclen /* lrecl = 32767 */; 
  input string $varying32767. reclen;
  /* Creating variables for data file name  and data year */
  d_position = prxmatch('m/class="OrangeBox"/',string);         
  if d_position ^= 0 then do;
    fname = scan(scan(scan(string, 2, '#'), 2, '>'), -2,'<') ;
    if find(string,'Longitidinal') ^= 0 then data_year = '  '; 
    else data_year = substr(fname, prxmatch(re,fname),4);
  end;
  put fname = ;
  put data_year=;
  datalines;
<td width="80%" class="OrangeBox" ><strong><font color="#000000">MEPS HC-001: 1996 Panel Round 1 Population Characteristics</font></strong></td>
<td width="80%" class="OrangeBox" ><strong><font color="#000000">MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Year Longitudinal Data File</font></strong></td>
;
run;
```

- The SAS Log:

```
fname=MEPS HC-001: 1996 Panel Round 1 Population Characteristics
data_year=1996
NOTE: Invalid second argument to function SUBSTR at line 3159 column 30.
fname=MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Year Longitudinal Data File
data_year=
RULE:         ----+----1----+----2----+----3----+----4----+----5----+----6----+----7----+----8----+----9----+----0
3165          <td width="80%" class="OrangeBox" ><strong><font color="#000000">MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Ye
         101  ar Longitudinal Data File</font></strong></td>
re=1 data_year=  fname=MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Year Longitudinal Data File reclen=160
string=<td width="80%" class="OrangeBox" ><strong><font color="#000000">MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Year Longitudinal Data File
</font></strong></td> d_position=17 _ERROR_=1 _N_=2
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

Please see above what I have tried.
I was expecting the same results in the SAS Log above, but without the Note: Invalid second argument to function SUBSTR at line 3159 column 30.

Comment: We can only tell you what changes to make, if you clearly explain us the results you desire.

Comment: Please also be specific on the input. For instance, will the `td`-tag always be closed on the same line as on which it is opened?

Comment: I am getting the expected results:

Comment: fname=MEPS HC-001: 1996 Panel Round 1 Population Characteristics
data_year=1996
NOTE: Invalid second argument to function SUBSTR at line 3159 column 30.
fname=MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Year Longitudinal Data File
data_year=

Comment: The only issue is: NOTE: Invalid second argument to the function SUBSTR.

Comment: Yes, the td-tag should be there as is.

Comment: The `NOTE:` is evident: if you don't find `\d{4} | \d{4}-d{4}`, `trcMatch` returns `0` and that is not a valid second argument of `substr()`.

Comment: You might get the right result now, but your code is do bad, you can't trust it will keep doing so with other data.

Comment: Tour data lines don't contain counter examples, so you did not test your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about like this:

```
data have;
  infile cards;
  input;
  fname = scan(scan(_infile_, -4, "/"),-1,"<>");
  n = _N_;
  keep fname n;
datalines;
<td width="80%" class="OrangeBox" ><strong><font color="#000000">MEPS HC-001: 1996 Panel Round 1 Population Characteristics</font></strong></td>
<td width="80%" class="OrangeBox" ><strong><font color="#000000">MEPS HC-226: MEPS Panel 23 Three-Year Longitudinal Data File</font></strong></td>
;
run;
data want;
  set have(in=a where=(not(fname like '%Longitudinal%'))) 
      have(in=b where=(    fname like '%Longitudinal%'));
  if a then data_year = scan(scan(fname, 2, ":"),1," ");
run;
proc sort data=want;
  by n;
run;
```

Comment: Your suggested code provides me with the desired results. Thank you! But I am still looking for a solution to revise my original code to use it in my macro program.